# constructor of nType hits on creating a List<nType> object?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, c#-4.0, constructor

I am just curious if the line below hits the constructor of Employee on execution of this line?

```
List<Employee> exmployees = new List<Employee>();
```

Comment: No.............

Comment: The constructor for a List of type `Employee` never creates an `Employee` object on its own. When would it even do that?

Comment: @NiyokoYuliawan: Thanks but when?

Comment: @Abion47: Thanks but when the constructor is fired for similar code?

Comment: @Learner The List *never* calls the constructor for the object. That's your job when you call, for example, `list.Add(new Employee(...));`

Comment: @Abion47: Thanks but you missed a vote by not answering in clarity with an example like the guy below did and secured a vote :) Anyway, cheers man for your help.

Comment: @Learner ...Darn?

Comment: @Abion47: Abby, what is mean by Darn? lol

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you looking for this?

```
Employee = new List<Employee>(){ new Employee("1")//Here constructor get called, 
                                            new Employee("12"),
                                            new Employee("123") };
```

Comment: Thank you, makes a little sense to me, but I was curious if just not using new keyword with Employee but with List<Employee> would hits the constructor. But your answer gave me better clarity or next question answer :)